# How to change angular service variable value?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my angular service.ts code. How I change this 'loginstatus' variable value to 'true' in login() method of app.componenent.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    
 var loginstatus:false;
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class CurdService {
    
      constructor() { }
     
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable loginstatus is outside the scope of your service. Modify it this way

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CurdService {
  loginstatus = false
  constructor() { }
 
}
```

And then, in your app.component inject your service:

```
constructor(curdService: CurdService) {
   this.curdService.loginstatus = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared `loginstatus` as a `var` which can't be accessed outside the service file. Just remove the `var` and declare the variable inside your service class file.

Please Note: Though this may work, I recommend using the variables inside the component and not in the services as it is not the responsibility of a Service class, but a Component class. Still, you need it in services, consider using `Subject()` or `BehaviorSubject()` as services are used in multiple places (worth considering that `Subjects` will lose values when the page is refreshed and mechanisms to tackle that needs to be in-place)!

Comment: Thank you. I got that idea.